# osx - update ruby with Homebrew

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

Sorry to ask that. I read a lot of posts here and there about my problem, but none fix it.
I installed ruby with homebrew. Last brew update, i tried to update my shell too, but nothing seems to work:

```
[jc@mbajc ~]$ ll /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  11 jc  admin   374B 24 oct 23:31 2.1.3_1
drwxr-xr-x  11 jc  admin   374B 29 oct 09:17 2.1.4
[jc@mbajc ~]$ 

[jc@mbajc ~]$ cat .bash_profile | grep ruby
#export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.3_1/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.4/bin:$PATH"

[jc@mbajc ~]$ which -a ruby 
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.4/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

I `brew unlink ruby`, then `brew link ruby`.
and:
`ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin13.0]`
What should i do ?
thanks

**EDIT** fix with:
`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`
and `brew unlink ruby && brew uninstall ruby && brew link ruby`

Comment: The idea of `homebrew` (I think) is that you put `/usr/local/bin` at the start of your PATH, and it decides which `ruby` you run by the way it is linked. But you have set your PATH to explicitly NOT do what `homebrew` intends and over-ridden it by putting `/Cellar/..2.1.4...` in your PATH. Try `ls -l /usr/local/bin/ruby` and see if the the `brew link` has set that correctly and if it has, remove your override from your `PATH`.

Comment: ok i delete ```Cellar/```in my PATH, use ```/usr/local/bin``` instead. brew still link ruby to the old one.

Comment: Did you rehash with `hash -r`?

Comment: Or try removing the old one and re-installing the new one.

Comment: no i didn't but i have fixed it, but not the way i intented, as to keep the old one. anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: I would recommend using http://rvm.io/ or https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv to install and manage Rubies. In the long run you will very likely be working on several projects which may use different versions of Ruby. Handling that with homebrew is a PITA.

Comment: yeah i should have a look at it. Not the first i heard about it.